# Side-by-side plotting in ReporteRs using addImage

Tags: r, reporters

I am using the ReporteRs package to automatically create a docx document. To this end, I need to put two external images side by side. Is it not an option manually combining them before using them in R
, since that would be a large number of combinations.

```
library("ReporteRs")
doc <- docx()
doc <- addImage(doc,"image1.png",par.properties = parLeft(), height=1, width=1)
doc <- addImage(doc,"image2.png",par.properties = parLeft(), height=1, width=1)
writeDoc(doc, file = "example.docx")
```

How can I do this so the plots are side by side, and not under/over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 different methods:

```
# png(filename = "image1.png")
# barplot(1:10)
# dev.off()
# 
# png(filename = "image2.png")
# barplot(1:10)
# dev.off()

library(ReporteRs)
library(magrittr)
```

#### method 1: with a section

```
docx() %>% 
  addSection(ncol = 2, space_between = 0.1) %>% 
  addImage( "image1.png",par.properties = parLeft(), height=1, width=1) %>% 
  addColumnBreak() %>% 
  addImage( "image2.png",par.properties = parLeft(), height=1, width=1) %>% 
  addSection( ncol = 1 ) %>% 
  writeDoc( file = "example1.docx")
```

#### method 2 : with a table

```
dat <- matrix("", nrow = 1, ncol = 2) # dummy empty table
# Flextable - one line, 2 columns
ft <- FlexTable(dat, header.columns = F, add.rownames = F) 
ft[1,1] <- pot_img("image1.png", height=1, width=1) # add image1 to cell 1
ft[1,2] <- pot_img("image2.png", height=1, width=1) # add image2 to cell 2

docx() %>% 
  addFlexTable( ft ) %>% 
  writeDoc(file = "example2.docx")
```

Comment: I had the thought that it could be done with a FlexTable. I didnt thought of addSection being an option. Thank you

Comment: I tried this with some ggplots instead of images, the section method adds an entire pagebreak and the table method returns an error when I put my plot inside the matrix. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel `pot_img` is expecting a path to an image, not a ggplot object.