# How to remove linebreak after ReporteRs::addPlot()?

Tags: r, line-breaks, reporters

I'm using the ReporteRs package to generate my reports.

But whenever I want to add a plot, the function adds a newline after.

How can I prevent this so I can put 2 plots on the same line ?

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38769517/2615411

Comment: Very interesting, but it doesn't work with ggplots

Answer (score 1):

`addPlot` adds a plot in a new paragraph. You should use `pot_img` (and generate the image on your own) to keep images in a single paragraph.

The link provided by @Victorp is the correct one.